# Functions with exploding slope have exploding intercept?

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if it is true that, for a $C^1$ function $f$,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{|x|\rightarrow+\infty}|f'(x)|=+\infty
\end{equation}
implies
\begin{equation}
\lim_{|x|\rightarrow+\infty}\left|f(x)-f'(x)\cdot x\right|=+\infty
\end{equation}
The condition sounds natural to me, since it means when the tangent line has a slope going to infinity the intercept must go to ininity too.

I know there is a proof in the case $f$ is convex; however, in the general case, I wasn't able to find neither a counterexample nor a proof.

Comment: I am thinking of something like $\sin$ function, for which fluctuations become more and more often. Does not really satisfy the first property, but maybe something along those lines.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something oscillating could do the job. I've tried with $\sin(x)+x$, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|f(x)-f'(x)x|\le M$ then
$$
\left|\left(\frac{f(x)}x\right)'\right|\le \frac{M}{x^2},
$$
and thus
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)}x-f(1)\right|\le M\left(1-\frac1x\right)\implies |f(x)-f(1)·x|\le M·|x-1|
$$
On the other hand, to have $f'(x)>2M+1$ for $x>x_0$ as it is required for divergence to infinity (switch sign if necessary), the function needs to satisfy
$$
f(x)>f(x_0)+(2M+1)·(x-x_0)
$$
which implies that the function will in finite time leave the cone prescribed by the first inequality. This proves the impossibility of such a function.

Comment: How did you deduce $|f(x)/x-f(1)|\leq M(1-1/x)$?

Comment: By integrating. $|g(b)-g(a)|=|\int_a^b g'(s)ds|\le\int_a^b|g'(s)|\,ds$ and then apply the bound, which here is $|g'(x)|\le M/x^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something, but isn't $(b-a)$ multiplied by the bound equal to $(x-1)M/x^2$? How do you get $M(1-1/x)$ from that?

Comment: $\int_a^b\frac1{s^2}ds=\frac1a-\frac1b$ is an upper bound for $|\frac{f(b)}b-\frac{f(a)}a|/M$. Now multiply by $ab$ to get $|af(b)-bf(a)|\le M(b-a)$, then set $a=1$ and $b=x$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.